# Ruby - There's an array of integers given. I have to find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product

Tags: arrays, ruby, function

This little thing in the arcade mode of `codesignal.com` is literally killing me.

Here's the problem-

Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.
For inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], the output should be
adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21. 7 and 3 produce the largest product.

This is the code I could manage:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)
    for check in 0..(inputArray.length-1)
        previous = -5000000000000000000000000000000       
        if check < inputArray.length-1
            name = inputArray[check] * inputArray[check+1]
            chosen = name if name > previous
        end
    end
    return chosen
end
```

This gives `3/9` correct answers.

Answer (score 6):

```
def max_product_adjacent_elements(arr)
  arr.each_cons(2).max_by { |x,y| x*y }.reduce(:*)
end

arr = (-50..100).to_a.sample(10)
  #=> [100, 0, 4, 20, -45, 71, 21, 39, 40, -33]

max_product_adjacent_elements(arr)
  #=> 1560 (39*40)
```

See [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Here's another way.

```
mx = -Float::INFINITY
enum = arr.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [63, 76, 31, 25, 38, 91, 87, 34, 86, 72]:each>
loop { mx = [mx, enum.next * enum.peek].max }
mx
  #=> 1560
```

When the enumerator is at its last position in `arr`, [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopIteration` exception that [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles by breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Slight tweak...it should be: `arr.each_cons(2).max_by { |x,y| x*y }.reduce(:*)`.  The OP said they need to return the largest actual product, not an array containing the two factors.

Comment: Do we need every adjacent pairing from the array? It seems we only need the array's max value and its adjacent friends (similarly for negatives, the minimum value respectively), then finding the max product from this.

Comment: @SagarPandya if I understand you correctly then `[6, 7, 2, 10, 3]` is a counter point...if you just look at the max value and adjacent friends you'd only see `[2, 10, 3]` and get `30`, missing that `6 * 7 == 42`

Comment: @Simple Ahhh of course, I'm completely wrong. Good example.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody would consider first and last elements as adjacent:

```
def max_product_adjacent_elements_circular(arr)
  prod = 0
  arr.size.times do
    new_prod = arr.rotate![0..1].reduce(:*)
    prod = new_prod if new_prod > prod
  end
  prod
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr.each_cons(2).max_by{|x, y| x*y }.inject(:*)`

- [`each_cons(N)`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons) function takes the block which is used to check the condition and N which specifies the number of consecutive elements to take.
- follow by [`max`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max) which will return the maximum pair outcome
- [`inject(:*)`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max) multiply the two

Comment: NVM this is actually the same solution presented by Cary. Inject and Reduce are aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way

```
def multiply_to(array)
      array.each_cons(2).max_by { |a,b| a*b }.reduce(:*)
    end
    array = [4,7,9,13,4,7,91,13,100,50].max(2)
    puts multiply_to array
    array1 = [4,7,9,13,4,7,91,13,100,50].min(2)
    puts multiply_to array1
```